# Extracting AUCs from Gradient Boosted Models from 200 manually created replicates in R

Tags: r, automation, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I have been working on getting a bootstrapped confidence interval around AUCs generated in a gradient boosted machine learning algorithm with a continuous outcome.
Below is the code for one iteration of what needs to be repeated at least 200 times:

1. Resample the main dataset (n=1000) with replacement
2. Quantile normalize the outcome variable
3. Run GBM on the resampled dataset and extract AUC

I know in SAS I could use a macro that would run through this code 200 times, creating 200 datasets and extracting 200 AUC's I could merge, but I don't know how I would loop this in R.

```
#calling required packages
library("WVPlots")
source('functions.R')
require(gbm)


#generating some data    
main<-matrix(
  replicate(52,rnorm(1132)),
  ncol=52,
  nrow=1132,
  dimnames = list(
    1:1132,
    1:52)
)
colnames(main)[1] <- "PctControl"


#creating resampled dataset BS[1] (so my aim is to repeat this for BS[1:200]

BS1=matrix(
  rep(as.numeric(NA)), 
  nrow=1000, 
  ncol= ncol(main), 
  dimnames= list(1:1000, colnames(main))
              )

BS1[1:1000,]<-as.matrix (main[sample(nrow(main),size=1000,replace=TRUE),])
BS1<-BS1[order(BS1[,1]),]


Survival <- as.numeric (BS1[,1])

NormedSurvival<- as.numeric( ppoints(Survival) )
BS1<-cbind (NormedSurvival, BS1)

BS1<-as.data.frame(BS1[,-2])


#fitting the GBM model

scwrpxy.fit.gbm = gbm(NormedSurvival~.,
                      data=BS1,
                      n.trees = 50, verbose = T, shrinkage = 0.005, 
                      bag.fraction = 0.25,          # subsampling fraction, 0.5 is probably best
                      train.fraction = 0.3,
                      interaction.depth = 3, n.minobsinnode = 10, distribution = "gaussian",
                      cv.folds = 3) 

summary(scwrpxy.fit.gbm)

#Calculating AUC

predictedGBM<-as.numeric(predict.gbm (scwrpxy.fit.gbm, 
                                      n.trees = 500, 
                                      shrinkage = 0.005, 
                                      interaction.depth=3,
                                      bag.fraction=0.5,
                                      train.fraction=0.3,
                                      cv.folds = 5,  
                                      distribution="gaussian"))


observedGBM<-as.numeric(BS1$NormedSurvival)

TestTox<-as.data.frame(cbind(observedGBM,predictedGBM))

ROCPlot(TestTox,'predictedGBM','observedGBM','gbm model')
gbmAUC = as.numeric(pROC::auc(TestTox$observedGBM,TestTox$predictedGBM))
print(gbmAUC)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SAS you need to `PROC APPEND` or `DATA` step to append datasets. In R you need to `rbind()` for the same thing. so do something like:

```
if !exists(baseAUC) 
  baseAUC <- gbmAUC
else 
  baseAUC <- rbind(baseAUC,gbmAUC)
```